# Running SignalR Service with Azure function not working

Tags: javascript, signalr, azure-functions, signalr-hub, signalr-2

I'm trying to run SignalR Service using azure functions with nodeJS to be able send messages to react. [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/learn/modules/automatic-update-of-a-webapp-using-azure-functions-and-signalr/5-exercise-enable-automatic-updates-in-a-web-app-using-signalr)

Actually I just want to set up backend services ( SignalR + send messages functions ) locally.

For that I have created SignalR function:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req, connectionInfo) {
    console.log(connectionInfo)
    context.res.body = connectionInfo;
};
```

in `function.json`

```
{
    "bindings": [
    {
        "authLevel": "anonymous",
        "type": "httpTrigger",
        "direction": "in",
        "name": "request",
        "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "http",
        "direction": "out",
        "name": "res"
    },
    {
        "type": "signalR",
        "name": "signalRMessages",
        "connectionStringSetting": "Endpoint=https://xxxx.service.signalr.net;AccessKey=XXXXXXx;Version=1.0;",
        "hubName": "XXXXX",
        "direction": "out"
    }
    ]
}
```

Then in my second function which will send messages to SignalR service:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    const name = (req.query.name || (req.body && req.body.name));
    const responseMessage = name
        ? "Hello, " + name + ". This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
        : "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.";

    const updates = [{
        target: 'updated',
        arguments: [responseMessage]
    }];
    context.bindings.signalRMessages = updates;
    context.done();


}
```

in `function.json`

```
{
    "bindings": [
    {
        "authLevel": "anonymous",
        "type": "httpTrigger",
        "direction": "in",
        "name": "req",
        "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "http",
        "direction": "out",
        "name": "res"
    },
    {
        "type": "signalRConnectionInfo",
        "name": "connectionInfo",
        "hubName": "xxxxxx", <== here I putted the SignalR service name without the domaine
        "direction": "in",
        "connectionStringSetting": "Endpoint=https://XXXXX.service.signalr.net;AccessKey=XXXXXX;Version=1.0;"
    }
    ]
}
```

Then I `local.setting.json`

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "AzureSignalRConnectionString": "Endpoint=https://xxxxxx.service.signalr.net;AccessKey=xxxxxxxxx;Version=1.0;"
    },
    "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7072,
    "CORS": "*"
    }
}
```

I have also set `service mode` to `serverless` in SignalR Service setting.

Now I'm trying to test that by running the `sendmessages` function in the browser which should trigger the `signalR` function

But when I run the `sendMessages` function on browser the `SignalR Serice function` is not triggered and context.bindings contains only `req`( no `res` and `sendMessages` listed in `function.json`)

Am I missing something in my configuration ?

Comment: I had a lot of trouble too.. But as far as I can see there are a lot differences in your functions.json to the example https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-tutorial-authenticate-azure-functions.  Like in negotiate.json the propperties type, name, direction . Please adjust these and try again.